# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql

i am having hard time determining the length of a Decimal data type. The data i have in column is like 0.08,1.2,12.35,121.36. Now if i go for (2,2) it throws an error : Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. Just wondering should it be (6,2)? and if yes can anybody tell me Why 6 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In syntax like

```
NUMERIC(precision, scale)
```

*precision* is the total number of digits (count digits on both sides of the decimal point), and *scale* is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @Programmer, so in your example, you would need `Numeric(5,2)` to accommodate your longest number `121.36`, which has 5 digits, and 2 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @RB: At the very least. But the OP also needs to think about what to do with the result of expressions like `3.33 * 5.12` (17.0496).

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, should be `NUMERIC(5,2)` - meaning five numbers in total and 2 after the decimal point.